How to write a function in LATEX whose value is different in [0,1/3), [1/3,1/2) ...?
I am writing a presentation to present my understanding of a research paper and I am new to LATEX. The professors at my uni didn't told anyone to write in LATEX but its very useful, I have read. I am trying to learn it. I am using overleaf website.
Can you please let me know how to write the code of this function in LATEX?

I shall be grateful for the help.

Please show us what you tried in a minimal working example (MWE).

Have a look into the documentation of package amsmath. If you still have problems, show the code you've tried. BTW:Usually I would use a kind of case construct with a brace  for such a function.

Please don't set whole words like "if" in math mode. This will destroy the kerning.

Does the vertical alignment have to occur on the second row of the right-hand-side material? And, is your presentation based on beamer document?

With the cases environment:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \[\rho_0(x) = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if } 0           \le x < \frac{1}{3},\\
    1 & \text{if } \frac{1}{3} \le x < \frac{1}{2},\\
    2 & \text{if } \frac{1}{2} \le x < \frac{2}{3},\\
    3 & \text{if } \frac{2}{3} \le x < \frac{5}{6},\\
    4 & \text{if } \frac{5}{6} \le x < 1
  \end{cases}\]
\end{document}



Strongly recommend replacing \text with \textup to avoid unintentionally using the ambient style. Also, the poster is new to LaTeX and may not use LuaLaTeX, so I recommend replacing ≤ with \le to make it easier for them to use your answer.

@SandyG Why should we avoid using the ambient style? If in an (italic) proof environment, I'd expect text to be in italics.

For fun 
By use the tblr of tabularray package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \[
\rho_0(x) = \left\{ \begin{tblr}{@{} l Q[l, preto={\textup{if\ }}]}
        0 & 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{3}, \\
        1 & \frac{1}{3} \leq x < \frac{1}{2}, \\
        2 & \frac{1}{2} \leq x < \frac{2}{3}, \\
        3 & \frac{2}{3} \leq x < \frac{5}{6}, \\
        4 & \frac{5}{6} \leq x < 1.
                    \end{tblr}\right.
    \]
\end{document}



Two other options:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \rho_0(x) =
    \begin{array}{ll}
        0 & \text{if } 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{3}, \\ 
        1 & \text{if } \frac{1}{3} \leq x < \frac{1}{2}, \\
        2 & \text{if } \frac{1}{2} \leq x < \frac{2}{3}, \\
        3 & \text{if } \frac{2}{3} \leq x < \frac{5}{6}, \\
        4 & \text{if } \frac{5}{6} \leq x < 1.
    \end{array}
    \]


    \[
    \rho_0(x) = 
    \begin{aligned}
        &0 \quad \text{if } 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{3}, \\
        &1 \quad \text{if } \frac{1}{3} \leq x < \frac{1}{2}, \\
        &2 \quad \text{if } \frac{1}{2} \leq x < \frac{2}{3}, \\
        &3 \quad \text{if } \frac{2}{3} \leq x < \frac{5}{6}, \\
        &4 \quad \text{if } \frac{5}{6} \leq x < 1.
    \end{aligned}
    \]  
\end{document


But use \[...\] instead of $$...$$.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

I gather that the = symbol has to be aligned on the second row. To achieve this look, the following solution may be of interest. Note that the solution assumes that you'll be using the beamer document class since you'll be giving a presentation.

It's important to render the "if" words in text mode rather than in math mode.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{arev}  % nice sans-serif text and math font package
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] % top alignment (just for this example)
\frametitle{Set the frame title here}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{array}{@{} l}
  \\ \rho_0(x)= \\ \\ \\ \null
\end{array}
\begin{array}{@{} l @{\;} L @{}}
  0 & if $0          \le x <\frac{1}{3}$, \\
  1 & if $\frac{1}{3}\le x <\frac{1}{2}$, \\
  2 & if $\frac{1}{2}\le x <\frac{2}{3}$, \\
  3 & if $\frac{2}{3}\le x <\frac{5}{6}$, \\
  4 & if $\frac{5}{6}\le x <1$. 
\end{array}
\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}

